# Confidence intervals for ordered probit

Tags: confidence-interval, stata, ordinal-data, probit

I'm attempting to compute confidence intervals for an ordered probit. I am a graduate student and it was suggested as one of the tasks to add to my final paper. I have found a few papers discussing it but I'm not sure if this has to be done manually. I am using Stata.

The confidence intervals are for the predicted probabilities. My model has 3 discrete outcomes.

IE. With 95% confidence the outcome will be y=1 or y=2

Comment: Can you clarify what you want? Are you asking for confidence intervals for a parameter estimate? For the thresholds? Do you want a confidence band for the model? Be aware that your question may be addressed w/o providing you w/ Stata code.

Comment: Sorry, confidence intervals for the estimates. The model has three discrete outcomes.

Comment: You mean like a CI for the predicted outcome category for a given observation?

Comment: Yes, seems redundant to myself.but my professor is grading based on these changes so I am obligated to do so.

Comment: I feel your pain...

Answer (score 1):

This is a partial solution, but maybe it will be useful start.

The usual way of doing this is with `predictnl`'s `ci` option, which will give you predicted probability and a confidence interval for each observation. But this will give you some CI endpoints that fall outside [0,1] interval since Stata is not aware that it is dealing with probabilities when applying the delta method:

```
use "http://www.stata-press.com/data/r13/fullauto", clear
oprobit rep77 foreign length mpg

/* Automated: CIs outside [0,1] */
predictnl poor = predict(outcome(1)), ci(poor_lb poor_ub)
predictnl fair = predict(outcome(2)), ci(fair_lb fair_ub)
predictnl avg  = predict(outcome(3)), ci(avg_lb avg_ub)
predictnl good = predict(outcome(4)), ci(good_lb good_ub)
predictnl exc  = predict(outcome(5)), ci(exc_lb exc_ub)
```

I don't believe that simply setting the problematic endpoints to zero or one is the correct thing to do.

Next I tried defining [the expressions by hand](http://www.stata.com/manuals13/roprobitpostestimation.pdf#page=4), but that had the same problem:

```
/* Manual #1: CIs still outside [0,1] */
predictnl exc2  = normal(xb() - _b[/cut4]), ci(exc_lb2 exc_ub2)
predictnl good2 = normal(_b[/cut4]-xb()) - normal(_b[/cut3]-xb()), ci(good_lb2 good_ub2)
predictnl avg2  = normal(_b[/cut3]-xb()) - normal(_b[/cut2]-xb()), ci(avg_lb2 avg_ub2)
predictnl fair2 = normal(_b[/cut2]-xb()) - normal(_b[/cut1]-xb()), ci(fair_lb2 fair_ub2)
predictnl poor2 = normal(_b[/cut1]-xb()), ci(poor_lb2 poor_ub2)
```

Here `xb()` is shorthand for the linear index function of the coefficients and the predictors.

Calculating the linear index and getting CIs for that, and then taking the normal transform seems to work much better, but I am not sure how to apply that approach on the middle outcomes, where the predicted probability is a difference of two normal CDFs:

```
/* Manual #2 */
predictnl exc3  = xb()-_b[/cut4], ci(exc_lb3 exc_ub3)
predictnl poor3 = _b[/cut1]-xb(), ci(poor_lb3 poor_ub3)

foreach var of varlist *3 {
    replace `var' = normal(`var')
}
```

This will get you 2 of the 3 CIs for each observation.

Comment: Great, thank you! I think this will give me a good start.